# Does the speed of the processor affect the speed of consistency check?

Tags: synology

I've bought a `DS918+` and I have 2x10Tb + 2x3Tb.

I configured it that way:

- 1x10Tb + 2x3Tb for data
- 1x10Tb for consistency check

One 1x10Tb failed.

I've changed this drive 3 days ago and now it's only 19% done.
1/5. This means 12 days to finish! Even though I strongly doubt it, I've read in a lot of places that this is normal.

I was wondering if the speed of the processor affects the speed of consistency check?

Comment: With hard disk drives that big, I would say thats probably normal.  Especially if they are full.  Its more about the speed of the drives than the CPU in the NAS.

Comment: May I ask you to answer, this is a valid answer!

Comment: on a side note, you might want to consider a RAID-10 setup depending on your needs.  You get redundancy and speed, at the cost of half your storage space.

Comment: @keltari - dead right on speed - a rebuild will typically take that long regardless of how full partition is as RAID works at a block level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This speed seems within reason.  While the NAS's CPU is part of the equation, the real slowdown is the drives themselves.  When rebuilding the RAID (regardless of the method), the NAS has to read each bit off of all the disks, perform a calculation (like an XOR), and finally write the data to disk.  Traditional spinning platter hard disks are the slowest part of a computer (or NAS in this case).  Couple this with there being many terabytes of data, then you are looking at a lengthy rebuild time.